# What does the skiprows parameter do in read_csv()?

Tags: pandas

`ds=pd.read_csv('lrn.csv', skiprows=0)`

What does changing the value of skiprows to a non-zero number do?

Answer (score 0):

The read_csv() method has an option for skiprows that is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv). Putting a number other than `0` will cause pandas to ignore the first `n` rows. If you give us more context as to why you are trying to use the skiprows parameter in the first place we can give you a more helpful answer beyond just what skiprows is doing.

Comment: Well I just wanted to remove the header of the file. Using ds=pd.read_csv('lrn.csv', skiprows=1), I can skip first line (like column names: name, age, sex etc.) however if I tried to change the value from 1 to another number entire value dataset changed.

Comment: Have you tried using the header parameter in combination with the skiprows parameter? Together you can set the `n`th row as a header by skipping `n-1` rows and using the 'n'th for the header parameter

Comment: Also why are you trying to skip more than one line? What is wrong with lines 2-n?

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong however I was just trying to experiment... And i was looking for the explanation... Because normal things easily approachable but what if there's a change in it!! I'll try to work on the alternate header parameter. TY

Comment: If the answer was helpful considering clicking accept (green checkmark) so others can more easily find answers they are looking for.